# Send email with PHP language

Tags: php, email

I am Dylane, and I have a trouble with my PHP code for sending an email.
The code succeeded to send an email just to certain mail addresses, but does not send to the other (by example: Gmail, outlook, yahoo, etc.).

Can someone advise?

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
$mail = 'my@domain.com'; // email.
if (preg_match("#^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$#", $mail))
{
    $passage_ligne = "\r\n";
}
else
{
    $passage_ligne = "\n";
}
//===== HTML format.
$message_txt = "TEXT goes here!";

$message_html = "<html><head></head><body> HTML TEXT</body></html>";
//==========

//=====Creation of Création de la boundary
$boundary = "-----=".md5(rand());
//==========

//=====Subject defination.
$sujet = "Some subject";
//=========

//=====Header creation.
$header = "From: \"Something\"<my@domain.com>".$passage_ligne;
$header.= "Reply-to: \"Something\" <my@domain.com>".$passage_ligne;
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$passage_ligne;
$header.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".$passage_ligne." boundary=\"$boundary\"".$passage_ligne;
//==========

//=====Creation of message.
$message = $passage_ligne."--".$boundary.$passage_ligne;
//=====Ajout du message au format texte.
$message.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"".$passage_ligne;
$message.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne.$message_txt.$passage_ligne;
//==========
$message.= $passage_ligne."--".$boundary.$passage_ligne;
//=====Ajout du message au format HTML
$message.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"".$passage_ligne;
$message.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne.$message_html.$passage_ligne;
//==========
$message.= $passage_ligne."--".$boundary."--".$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne."--".$boundary."--".$passage_ligne;
//==========

//=====Send email.
mail($mail,$sujet,$message,$header);
//==========

header('location:../index.php');
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked Gmail's/Outlook's/Yahoo's spam box?

Comment: Why don't you just use phpmailer instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Swift Mailer is also a good option, beside PHP Mailer.

Comment: @Akintunde007 It would be nice to include [a link to said mail provider](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) `:-p`

Comment: @halojoy It would also be good to provide [a link to said mail provder](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer) `:-p`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reliably deliver email then you should set up the MX, RDNS and SPF records for the ip adress of the server from which you are sending out the emails. Without these records most recipient mail servers will treat these emails as spam.

Comment: While this is an absolutely valid note, it's by no means the complete answer ... which is far longer and far more complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers.

Best regard

Comment: @sridhar pandurangiah How can I proceed to set up MX, RDNS and SPF, please ?